# Area of the region enclosed by $y=x^2-1$, $y=2x-1$, and $y=x+1$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find the area of the region enclosed by $y=x^2-1$, $y=2x-1$, and $y=x+1$.

Like the question I asked before, I still do not understand how to find these areas.

Comment: Hint: Sketch the functions, find the intersection points and then set up the integrals. (You will need to set up 2 integrals).

Comment: Since you’ve accepted an answer, does that mean that you now understand how to solve other similar problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the intersection of $y=x^2-1$ and $y=x+1$.

$x^2-x-2=0$

$x=-1,2$

$$S1=\int_{-1}^2\left[x+1-\left(x^2-1\right)\right]dx$$

Find the intersection of $y=x^2-1$ and $y=2x-1$

$x^2-2x=0$

$x=0,2$

$$S2=\int_0^2\left[2x-1-\left(x^2-1\right)\right]dx$$

**What does $S1-S2$ give you?**

fast answer posted due to desmos 'misc' function.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using addition also.

Find the intersection of $y=2x-1$ and $y=x^2-1$

$x=0,2$

$$S1=\int_{-1}^0\left[x+1-\left(x^2-1\right)\right]dx$$

Find the intersection of $y=x^2-1$ and $y=x+1$

$x=-1,2$

$$S2=\int_0^2\left[x+1-\left(2x-1\right)\right]dx$$

**So, what can be done with $S1$ and $S2$?**

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

[image]

\begin{align} 
f_1(x)&=x^2-1
,\quad
f_2(x)=2x-1
,\quad
f_3(x)=x+1
,\\
A&=(-1,0),\quad B=(0,-1),\quad C=(2,3),\quad D=(0,1)
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
[ABCD]&=[ABD]+[BCD]
\\
&=
\int_{-1}^{0} \int_{f_1(x)}^{f_3(x)} 1\cdot\,dy \,dx
+\int_{0}^{2} \int_{f_2(x)}^{f_3(x)} 1\cdot\,dy \,dx
\\
&=
\int_{-1}^{0} \int_{x^2-1}^{x+1} 1\cdot\,dy \,dx
+\int_{0}^{2} \int_{2x-1}^{x+1} 1\cdot\,dy \,dx
\\
&=\int_{-1}^0 (x+2-x^2) \,dx
+\int_0^2 (2-x)\,dx
\\
&=\left(\left.\tfrac12\,x^2+2x-\tfrac13\,x^3\right)\right|_{-1}^0
+\left(\left. 2x-\tfrac12\,x^2 \right)\right|_{0}^2
\\
&=(-\tfrac12+2-\tfrac13)+(4-2)=4-\tfrac56
\\
&=\tfrac{19}6
.
\end{align}

Another possible way is to split the area into three parts:

\begin{align} 
[ABCD]&=[\triangle AOD]+[\triangle BCD]+[ABO]
\\
&=\tfrac12\,|AO|\cdot|OD|+\tfrac12\,|BD|\cdot|C_x-D_x|
+\left|\int_{-1}^{0}f_1(x)\,dx\right|
\\
&=\tfrac12\cdot1\cdot1+\tfrac12\cdot2\cdot2
+\left|\int_{-1}^{0}(x^2-1)\,dx\right|
\\
&=
\tfrac52
+\left|\left.(\tfrac13\,x^3-x)\right|_{-1}^{0}\right|
\\
&=
\tfrac52
+\left|\tfrac13-1\right|
=
\tfrac{5}2+\tfrac23 
=\tfrac{15}6+\tfrac46
=\tfrac{19}6
.
\end{align}